# местонахождение метода main любой программы

Tags: java, main

Скажите, пожалуйста, main метод не должен обязательно быть внутри класса?

Comment: это java, в ней все должно быть членом хоть какого-то класса. Или вы спрашиваете, должен ли у каждого класса быть метод `public static void main(String[] args)`? нет, не обязательно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должен, это условие нельзя нарушать. Не важно в каком классе, хотя бы одна функция `main()` должна быть.

Comment: а если у меня к примеру класс родитель (главный) и наследник, то я могу главный метод писать только в классе родителе в данном случае?

Comment: @MuscledBoy в любом.

Comment: а почему так? объясните пожалуйста?

Comment: @MuscledBoy потому что так решили создатели языка, делая максимальную объекто-ориентированность.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ